# Interpretation of pca plot

Tags: pca

I am looking at an example of using PCA:

https://wiki.q-researchsoftware.com/wiki/Principal_Components_Analysis_Biplot

Specifically, Example 2 has data

[image]

What are the points I'm looking at the biplot? Are those the tips of the projections of the vectors to the plane spanned by the principle axes? Are the lengths of the vectors related to the corresponding eigenvalues of the covariance matrix?

Comment: Welcome to cv, Primoz! I think you are right with your interpretation - did you check out the [related questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=PCA+Biplot+answers%3A1) ?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have looked at the other similar answers. My confusion is that the orange points correspond to the variables, so they are probably the projections. But what are the blue points that seem to correspond to the rows?

Comment: [This search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=pca+biplot) turns up many posts that answer your question.